# How to instert in bash a char at specific line and position in line

Tags: bash, char

I have a file, where I want to add a * char on specific line, and at a specific location in that line.

Is that possible?

Thank you

Comment: you can use substrings: https://stackoverflow.com/documentation/bash/502/shell-parameter-expansion/1654/substrings-and-subarrays#t=201704131226548345467

Comment: yes, it is possible

Comment: using substrings works just for one line, right? how can I change (add a character) a particular line in my test file?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a kind of external tool available to manipulate data such as sed or awk. You can use this tool directly from your command line or include it in your bash script.

Example:

```
$ a="This is a test program that will print
Hello World!
Test programm Finished" 
$ sed -E '2s/(.{4})/&\*/' <<<"$a"   #Or <file
#Output:
This is a test program that will print                                                                                                                                          
Hell*o World!                                                                                                                                                                   
Test programm Finished
```

In above test, we enter an asterisk after 4th char of line2.
If you want to operate on a file and make changes directly on the file then use `sed -E -i '....'`

Same result can also be achieved with gnu awk:

```
awk 'BEGIN{OFS=FS=""}NR==2{sub(/./,"&*",$4)}1' <<<"$a"
```

In pure bash you can achieve above output with something like this:

```
while read -r line;do
  let ++c
  [[ $c == 2 ]] && printf '%s*%s\n' "${line:0:4}" "${line:4}" || printf '%s\n' "${line}"
  # alternative: 
  # [[ $c == 2 ]] && echo "${line:0:4}*${line:4}" || echo "${line}"  
done <<<"$a"
#Alternative for file read:
# done <file >newfile
```

If your variable is just a single line, you don't need the loop. You can do it directly like:

```
printf '%s*%s\n' "${a:0:4}" "${a:4}"
# Or even 
printf '%s\n' "${a:0:4}*${a:4}" #or echo "${a:0:4}*${a:4}"
```

Comment: @DCuser Welcome. I will try to include a pure bash solution also.

Comment: @DCuser Pure bash solution added.

Comment: but this method just prints the modified line, it does not replace the content of the file that contains the line...right?

Comment: @DCUser You can replace the contents of the file using `sed -i `. -i means in-place editing of the file. For bash  solution you need to apply `>newfile `

Answer (score 0):

I suggest to use `sed`. If you want to insert an asterisk at the 2nd line at the 5th column:

```
sed -r "2s/^(.{5})(.*)$/\1*\2/" myfile.txt
```

`2s` says you are going to perform a substitution on the 2nd line. `^(.{5})(.*)$` says you are taking 5 characters from the beginning of the line and all characters after it. `\1*\2` says you are building the string from the first match (i.e. 5 beginning characters) then a `*` then the second match (i.e. characters until the end of the line).

If your line and column are in variables you can do something like that:

```
_line=5
_column=2
sed -r "${_line}s/^(.{${_column}})(.*)$/\1*\2/" myfile.txt
```